# Store an OAuth access token in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, oauth, token

I'm currently building an API in asp.net ( language that I'm not entirely confortable with ) and I'm dealing with some problems in the autentication.

Im using OAuth tokens to give a user access to data, and the user gets the token the moment he gives a correct email and password. So far, so good.

I need to store the token somewhere, and after a few days researching, I found that cookies are a good solution if configured properly. Thing is: If i store the token in a cookie, it will be exposed, right? A person can actually see it, and that's not what I intent to, or at least, just being able to see a hash of it.

I've read also about XSS and CSRF attacks, and for that I need to set it to HttpOnly and restrict to HTTPS connections only.

I've read tons of tutorials, but none actually worked out.
What am I missing? Are cookies not safe at all? Is there a better place to store it? 
Any help is apreciated

Here is the StartupAuth.cs:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using util_api.Providers;

namespace util_api
{
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // Para obter mais informações sobre a autenticação de configuração, visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Habilite o aplicativo para usar um cookie que armazena informações do usuário conectado
        // e um cookie que armazena informações temporárias sobre um usuário que faz login em um provedor de login de terceiros

        // Configure o aplicativo para fluxo com base em OAuth
        PublicClientId = "self";

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {

            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new OAuthProvider(),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),

            // Em modo de produção, defina AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true

        };

        // Habilite o aplicativo para usar tokens portadores na autenticação de usuários

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
  }
}
```

And the OAuthProvider.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using util_api.Models;
using util_api.Services;


namespace util_api.Providers
{
public class OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    #region[GrantResourceOwnerCredentials]
    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var userName = context.UserName;
            var password = context.Password;
            var userService = new UserService(); // our created one
            var user = userService.ValidateUser(userName, password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, Convert.ToString(user.ID)),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.NAME),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EMAIL)
                };
                ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                            Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);

                var properties = CreateProperties(user.ID.ToString());
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
                context.Validated(ticket);
            }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "O endereço eletrónico ou palavra passe estão incorretos. Por favor, verifique as suas credenciais.");
            }
        });
    }
    #endregion

    #region[ValidateClientAuthentication]
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == null)
            context.Validated();

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    #endregion

    #region[TokenEndpoint]
    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    #endregion

    #region[CreateProperties]
    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string id)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "id", id }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
    #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: if you store a cookie, users can see it.  users can see anything thats sent between the browser and your server though.

you posted code but did not describe what issue/question you have regarding that code.

Comment: @RobertLevy
Sorry, my bad not explaining right! This is the code i have right now that generates the token. When I call that endpoint - localhost:56758/api/Token - I get the token just the way it suposed to be. My issue /question is how to store it directly in a cookie, in the moment that this endpoint its called. Or if exists a better way / place to store it. Hope it clarified :)